# Rounded corners for internet explorer

Tags: internet-explorer, css

I'm working on this site http://www.claybrookanimalfeeds.co.uk/contact.php and I would like to get rounded corners on the shop opening times box on the right hand side.

Now I've managed to get them to work in Firefox, chrome and opera but for some reason they are not working in internet explorer. I've tried different ways of doing it (including PIE) but none of them seem to work. Either I've translated the code so that it fits mine wrongly or it's just not working.

Any help would be appreciated.

Here is the css I'm using (it's quite long), the part of the code I want to have the rounded corners on is under the opening times section

```
@charset "utf-8";
/* CSS Document */
body {
background-color:beige;
font-family: georgia,sans-serif;
color:#333;
margin:0;
padding:0;
}

#wrapper {
width:960px;
background-color:beige;
margin:0 auto;
}
/*Header*/
#header {
height:150px;
}

h1 {
text-align:center;
color:darkgoldenrod;
font-size:36px;
}

#p1 {
text-align:center;
color:darkgoldenrod;
font-size:18px;
}

/*Header End*/

/*Navigation Bar*/
#nav {
width:100%;
float:left;
margin: 0 0 1em 0;
padding:0;
background-color:darkgoldenrod;
border-bottom:1px solid #ccc;  
}

#nav ul {
list-style:none;
width:800px;
margin:0 auto;
margin-left:100px;
padding:0; 
}

#nav li {
float:left;
width:250px;
text-align:center;
}

#nav li a {
display:block;
padding:8px 15px;
text-decoration:none;
font-weight:bold;
color:white;
border-right:1px solid #ccc; 
}

#nav li:first-child a {
border-left:1px solid #ccc; 
}

#nav li a:hover {
color:white;
background-color:blue; 
}

/*Navigation Bar End*/
#content {
width:675px;
float:left;
margin-left:10px;
padding:10px;
}

/*Slideshow*/
#slide-show {
margin-left:150px;
}

#slide-images {
display:block;
margin:0px;
padding:0px;
width:300px;
height:224px;
overflow:hidden;
}

#slide-images li {
display:block;
list-style-type:none;
margin:0px;
padding:0px;
background-color:#FFFFFF;
}

#slide-images li img {
display:block;
background-color:#FFFFFF;
}
/*Slideshow End*/

/*Opening Times*/
#openingtimes
{
float:right;
height:200px;
width:200px;
background-color:white;
text-align:center;
border-style:solid;
border-width:medium;
border-color:black;
-moz-border-radius: 15px; /* Firefox */
-webkit-border-radius: 15px; /* Safari and Chrome */
border-radius: 15px;
-moz-box-shadow: 10px 10px 20px #000; /* Firefox */
-webkit-box-shadow: 10px 10px 20px #000; /* Safari and Chrome */
box-shadow: 10px 10px 20px #000;
}
/*Opening Times End*/

/*Form*/
#form {
float:left;
}
/*Form End*/

/*Sidebar*/
#sidebar {
width:200px;
float:left;
margin-left:10px;
margin-bottom:25px;
background-color:tan;
text-indent:10px;
-moz-box-shadow: 5px 5px 5px black;
-webkit-box-shadow: 5px 5px 5px black;
box-shadow: 5px 5px 5px black;
filter:
    progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.DropShadow(color=black, offx=5, offy=10)
}

#sidebar li {
list-style: none;
position: relative;
height: 30px;
padding:0 20px;
background-color:tan;
color: #45371E;
line-height: 20px;
cursor:pointer;
}

#sidebar li a {
text-decoration:none;
color: #45371E;
background-color:transparent;
display:block;
} 

#sidebar li:hover {
background-color: #CD853F;
} 
/*Sidebar End*/

/*Footer*/
#footer {
clear:both;
width:960px;
height:135px;
border-top:1px solid #ccc;
text-align:center;
}

#footer p {
padding:10px;
}
/*Footer End*/
```

Comment: also add some code and css of what you have tried

Comment: Can we see some code? I'd say border-radius combined with CSS3 Pie's fill should make it work in IE8. Have you followed the Pie "[Getting Started](http://css3pie.com/documentation/getting-started/)"? (Handily, the example they use is for rounded corners...)

Comment: hmmm, i followed the instructions but i wasn't entirely sure which files i needed to upload so i uploaded all of them but maybe i got the url wrong i'm not sure, it didn't seem to work.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`border-radius` property works on `IE9=+` so if you are trying it on `IE8 <=` than it wont work, better use jQuery instead

http://www.malsup.com/jquery/corner/

Also use this website to check CSS property support for various browser, very handy for developers

[www.caniuse.com](http://www.caniuse.com)

Comment: ...or use background images with conditional CSS for IE8.

Comment: @otinanai I would prefer jQuery instead of images, cuz surely images are not the best thing for this

Comment: I'm just pointing to an alternative solution. I'm not discouraging your suggestion. however, what's best for this issue is totally subjective.

Comment: @otinanai Some people stick to it and never go for better alternatives so instead never go for bad practice unless you've no other way :)

Comment: Some other people tend to avoid using js because there's a good chance that users disable js functionality. Also, there's no "bad practice" when it comes to resolving issues with old browsers. If it works, it's fine :)

Comment: @otinanai Yes, but here we are talking about front end, this wont damage much to his layout, where images will, it increases http requests, mobile users running low on bandwidth wont get to see background images if it fails to load, so as far as front end is concerned and a thing like this, it doesnt damage much, yea if you are using JS for form validation and you are not using Server side to validate you'll end up in big mess

Comment: I'm trying the image (ie print screening the webpage on firefox and pasting it into paint and then cropping the image and then upload the image for internet explorer. However if anyone still has a solution just for ie other than images then you can still post the answer here.

Comment: @Mr. Alien You forget that jQuery library also needs an http request to load. Also, js functions take up processing power that images do not require. Also, you can minimize http requests if you use sprites. Now that's a good practice! Moreover, http requests are not a concern because we're dealing with IE8 and mobile devices do not use such browsers

Comment: @otinanai Obviously sprites is a way to go and moreover most of designers do use jQuery library for designing websites :)

Comment: hahaha now this depends on designer to take a better approach

Comment: true! it all depends on the case and the designer. Let's see what Sonnyjimjr3 decides.

Comment: Ok for now I've decided to go for an image. I print screened Firefox and cropped the image so it just had the opening times and used that as an image on the website, so now it looks as though the ie version has rounded corners when actually it doesn't as it's just an image.

Comment: As entertaining as this little debate was I'll mark this answer as the correct one because it has given me an alternate solution to my problem. But if anyone comes up with another idea that might work for css then feel free to add solutions, just in a new answer rather than a new comment as i think this answer has way too many comments as it is.

Comment: Aaaargh! I should have answered instead of commenting! I enjoyed the debate though :):)

Answer (score 1):

So ie9 and above support this http://caniuse.com/border-radius 
For IE6+ you can use a polyfill: http://css3pie.com/

Hope this helps.

So for your example using CSSPIE:

```
border: 1px solid black;
padding: 60px 0;
text-align: center; width: 200px;
-webkit-border-radius: 15px;
-moz-border-radius: 15px;
border-radius: 15px;
behavior: url(/pie/PIE.htc);
```

Comment: As i've said in the original post I've tried csspie but whether I've translated it to fit my correctly or not I'm not sure because it doesn't seem to work.

Comment: I tried that and it didn't work, also I'm working in php and the file said to link it to the php file which i did but it still didn't work. I had removed it from the code as it wasn't working.